# "Leave on" vs "leave"

Tags: vocabulary

Can there be a missing **on** when I say *somebody **leaves** on some date*? For example, is it okay if I say:

> We'll have to **leave** September 1st, because we have to be back in school on the 2nd.

instead of:

> We'll have to **leave on** September 1st, because we have to be back in school on the 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your concern, it's because some native speakers skip certain words while having a normal, fast conversation with others and *yes, they are grammatically incorrect.*

The sentence **"We'll have to leave September 1st"** may sound as if you have heard it somewhere, but still it's grammatically wrong. Date, time and venue require a preposition if used after a verb. But in many informal, short conversation people skip these grammar rules, but that doesn't make it correct.

Therefore, the sentence **"We'll have to leave on September 1st"** is grammatically correct.

*Sometimes, native speakers are just lazy ;)*

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, as a Brit who has lived in the US for 20+ years, British English would always include the "on", whereas it is optional in American usage. In both cases there is an unstated object in the sentence, such as "here" or "home".

I think the answer depends on your intended audience: if they are expecting American English you can leave out the "on",  but if there are Brits or people expecting British usage, you should probably include it.

Comment: Dude, Americans are just lazy *lol*... It's grammatically incorrect. In lazy, fast conversations they skip certain words assuming they are **too obvious**. That's the only reason. They will never skip 'on' in their school exams. Keep my words. And *damn*, it's funny...

Comment: @RiyaAgarwal Yes, if you specify a time with 'leave' you have to do it completely. For example "We have to leave _on_ Tuesday", "We have to leave _at_ 10:00am", "We have to leave _by_ 10:00am on Tuesday" or "We have to leave _no later than_ 10:00am. You only omit a preposition if the time is expressed completely by the word you use, for example "We have to leave now", " We have to leave soon" and so on.